# JavaScript HTTP GET

Tags: javascript, php, ip, http-get

I have a questions about HTTP GET request made in Javascript:

1) How can this be done?

2) Can this be done like curl in php? I mean that i can get any webpage and parse its content and retrieve some info based on Regular expression?

3) Is such Http request made from server Ip address or client side Ip address?

```
private function getWebPage($url)
            {

                $options = array(
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
                    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
                    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
                    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
                    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
                    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
                    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
                    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
                    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
                );

                $ch      = curl_init( $url );
                curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
                $content = curl_exec( $ch );
                $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
                $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
                $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
                curl_close( $ch );

                $header['errno']   = $err;
                $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
                $header['content'] = $content;
                return $content;
            }
```

Comment: 1. Ajax, 2. Yes, but only on your own domain or if [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) is enabled on the remote site, 3. The HTTP request is made from the client's IP

Comment: You create http request with ajax but cross domain request can be done only if CORS is enabled or if you create proxy script using php.